# Why can't I use the localStorage in my .config when it's include in the .module definition?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
var app = angular
    .module('app', ['ui.router', 'admin', 'home', 'questions', 'ngResource', 'LocalStorageModule'])
    .config(['$sceProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', 'localStorageService',
        function ($sceProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider, localStorageService ) {

        $sceProvider.enabled(false);
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        localStorageService.add('adminContent', 'xx');
```

This is giving me an error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: localStorageService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/$injector/unpr?p0=localStorageService
    at hasOwnPropertyFn (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0-rc.2.js:78:12)
    at http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0-rc.2.js:2997:19
    at getService (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0-rc.2.js:3119:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0-rc.2.js:3140:13)
    at http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0-rc.2.js:3078:37
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0-rc.2.js:224:11)
    at loadModules (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0-rc.2.js:3065:5)
    at createInjector (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0-rc.2.js:3007:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0-rc.2.js:1152:20)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3…http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A81%2FScripts%2Fangular-v1.2.0-rc.2.js%3A1152%3A20)
```

Is it not possible to use localStorage in config like this? I have included the code for the localstorage module and it's loaded before the app.js.  It works in other parts of the application, but the same line does not work when placed in the app.config

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only providers and constants are injectable in configuration blocks. See the AngularJs documentation for more insights: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module (sektion "Module Loading & Dependencies").

> Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations
>   and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected
>   into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation
>   of services before they have been fully configured.

Comment: You can work around this with the `$injector`, can't you?

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer correctly answers the question, it does not offer any solution (for Angular newbies looking for the right way to do this).

You have access to services at run time, which happens after configuration. For instance:

```
angular.module('app').run(storeAdminContent);

storeAdminContent.$inject = ['localStorageService'];
function storeAdminContent(localStorageService) {
    localStorageService.add('adminContent', 'xx');
}
```

Comment: I want to check whether I have a session or not and run method would execute after config so ho do I check it before the routing defined in config?

Comment: It would be possible to do so, but it would be going against angular design. The administrator routes should always exist, but you should make sure the user is authenticated once they enter those routes. Another (perhaps better) option would be to have a completely separate angular application for the administrator side, and share code between them using node or bower modules.