# Use token from localStorageService with interceptor

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new to Angular, so it's perfectly possible I made some stupid mistakes.

What I'm trying to do is use a token that is saved in localStorage and put that in all requests.

I have this code block:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', 'localStorageService', function($httpProvider, localStorageService) {
  //Http Interceptor to check auth failures for xhr requests
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authHttpResponseInterceptor');
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token token=' + localStorageService.get("TemponiaToken")
}])
```

And I'm getting this error message:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: localStorageService
```

I found this question and answer which (I think) explains the problem: [Why can't I use the localStorage in my .config when it's include in the .module definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944268/why-can-i-not-use-the-localstorage-in-my-config-when-its-include-in-the-modul)

However: how can I solve this?  Change the .config into .run ?  Thanks for any pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer you found says is not possible to inject services during the config phase.

There are two possible solution to your problem.
The first one is to use the native `localStorage` object

```
localStorage.getItem("TemponiaToken") // it just works without injecting any service
```

The other one is to correctly define the `interceptor`

```
yourApp.factory('AuthInterceptor', function (localStorageService) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};                
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Token token=' + localStorageService.get("TemponiaToken")                    
            return config;
        }
    };
});

yourApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
});
```

Comment: Works great!  I used the interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) says thus:

Usage from config phase

To read and set values during the Angular config phase use the .get/.set functions provided by the provider.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngStorage'])
.config(['$localStorageProvider',
    function ($localStorageProvider) {
        $localStorageProvider.get('MyKey');

        $localStorageProvider.set('MyKey', { k: 'value' });
    }]);
```